# How to update state value inside Action?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am new in react development,

I have a state variable created inside constructor.

```
constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    this.state = {
      status: false,
    };

  }
```

i am using redux and i have a action method to update redux values.

```
 export const actionMethod = () => {

    return dispatch => {

      return fetch (

      )
        .then (response => response.json ())
        .then (responseJson => {

        // i want to update value of state here.
     //i tried this.setState ({status: true}); but its getting TypeError: //_this.setState is not a function

        })
        .catch (error => {
          console.error (error);

        });
    };
  };
```

Let me how to update status value inside actionMethod.

Comment: Is your 'Action method' here, is an action of redux? If yes, then you should not update your state inside it. Instead, you create your action and pass the payload data and use it inside a reducer to update the state of your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong here:

- A redux action is a function declared somewhere outside of a React component, so it has no access to your Component state or anything else which is outside of its function scope.
- You use reducers to update a global redux state, which can trigger automatic rerendering of React components (if used correctly)

I believe you first need a better understanding of react, before trying to integrate redux. You can update a component's state without redux just fine. First learn react and how react components can be updated and rerendered using props and state, then later see if your application could benefit from redux.